# Finding the Area of the Largest Isoceles Triangle

Tags: triangles, circles, area

Can you please help me find the answer to question (a)? I've been looking for the answer for hours. It's still wrong, please help

[image: Inscribed Isosceles Triangle Problem]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In particular, please write out the question, rather than linking to an image offsite. If you are not familiar with ways to format math here, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the center of the triangle to be O and let the triangle be ABC, with BC as the base.

Let D be the altitude from O to BC. Now as you can see from the image, OD = h. As B and C lie on the circle, OB = OC, so triangle OBC is isosceles. As you hopefully know, the altitude of an isosceles triangle is also its median. So, BD = CD. Since triangle ODC is right angled, we can write:

$$OD^2+CD^2=OC^2$$

Since, we know that OD = h, OC = radius of the circle = 6, we can write:
$$h^2+CD^2=6^2=36$$
$$\Rightarrow CD^2=36-h^2$$
$$\Rightarrow CD = \sqrt{36-h^2}$$
So, we can say that,
$$BC=BD+CD=CD+CD=2\sqrt{36-h^2}$$
As ABC is also a isosceles triangle, its altitude also passes through the midpoint of BC, aka D, so AD is the altitude of triangle ABC. We can see that AD passes through O from the figure, so we can say that,
$$AD=AO+OD=6+h$$
So, we can find the area of the triangle:

Area of triangle ABC = $\frac{1}{2}*AD*BC=\frac{1}{2}*(h+6)*(2\sqrt{36-h^2})=(h+6)\sqrt{36-h^2}$

Now we can maximize the area by taking its derivative with respect to h. We find that:
$$\frac{d}{dh}(h+6)\sqrt{36-h^2}=-\frac{2(h^2+3h-18)}{\sqrt{36-h^2}}$$
We set it to zero to find its maxima:
$$-\frac{2(h^2+3h-18)}{\sqrt{36-h^2}}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow h^2+3h-18=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (h+6)(h-3)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow h=-6,3$$
We know that, $h>0$ so, $h=3$ is either a minima or maxima. As we can easily minimize the area to zero by setting h to 6 and turning the area to zero, we know that this is a maxima. So we can find the maximum area by calculating the function we found earlier for $h=3$.
$$Area=(h+6)\sqrt{36-h^2}=(3+6)\sqrt{36-9}=9\sqrt{27}=27\sqrt{3}$$
Hopefully my answer helps you. This is my first answer so please try to give me any advice you can.